# How to get subfield-value through pipe function

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I’m writing a code for receiving a data from mongodb in golang.
My code is as below:

```
type DataContent struct {
    Create time.Time     `bson:"create"`
    Desc   string        `bson:"desc"`
}
type Data struct {
    Id      bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Desc    string        `bson:"desc"`
    Content DataContent `bson:"content"`
}

func get() error {
    result := []Data{}
    coll := session.DB(“”).C(“aaa”)
    project := bson.M{"$project": bson.M{"_id": 1, "desc": 1, "content": 1 }}
    err := coll.Pipe([]bson.M{project}).All(&result)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    data, err := json.Marshal(result)
    fmt.Printf("#####\n%s\n#####\n", string(data))
    return nil
}
```

Result of execution is as below:

```
#####
[{"Id":"58133f92cf4abf18c834750d", "Desc”:”reg1\n”,"Content":{"Create":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","Desc":""}},
{"Id":"58134bbbcf4abf18c8347513", "Desc”:”reg2\n”,”Content":{"Create":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","Desc”:””}}]
#####
```

Values for subfield of “Content” was not come.

I’ve run same process via terminal also. Result is as below:

```
> db.aaa.aggregate([{$project: { _id:1, desc:1, content:1}}])
[{"Id":"58133f92cf4abf18c834750d", "Desc”:”reg1\n”,"Content":{"Create":ISODate("2016-10-28T13:13:13.520Z"),"Desc”:”aaa”}},
{"Id":"58134bbbcf4abf18c8347513", "Desc”:”reg2\n”,”Content":{"Create":ISODate("2016-10-28T13:09:32.810Z"),"Desc”:””}}]
```

Does anyone let me know how to get subfield-value via pipe function?

---

In addition, “Content” has following structure.

```
Content : [
 {
    Create : ISODate(“…”),
    Desc : “…”
 },
 {
    Create : ISODate(“…”),
    Desc : “…”
 }
]
```

Comment: You're doing it right, and it works for me. This line though is a compile time error: `err = coll.Pipe(...`, `err` is not defined. I wonder what else is different in your code compared to what you've posted.

Comment: The cause of compile error was my copy error and corrected above code. I’ve checked my code again but there is no any other copy error. 
I’ve appended structure of “Content” to above post also.

Comment: I found the cause.
Correctly type of `Data.Struct` must be `[]DataContent`
Sorry for coming out with such a silly question.

Comment: Wait, your `Content` structure you posted at the end is an array, it can't be loaded into the `Content` field which is a single value of type `DataContent`. It should be a slice if so, e.g. `Content []DataContent`.

Comment: @icza Exactly.... Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Answering the question to not show up as unanswered anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Content` structure is not a single value but an array of values. This means it cannot be loaded into the field `Data.Content` which is a single value of type `DataContent`.

Change your `Data.Content` field to a slice type (`[]DataContent`) and it will work:

```
type Data struct {
    Id      bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Desc    string        `bson:"desc"`
    Content []DataContent `bson:"content"`
}
```

Comment: Yes. My code becomes work correctly. Thank you for the answer. : )